# Alert with cookies, calling a variable from inside another function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, cookies, alert

I'm trying to create an alert in JavaScript using cookies that both greets the user by name and tells them how many times they've won a specific game on the website. I have the user greeting working fine, but I can't seem to get the counter to work correctly. It involves calling variables that are altered by a previous function, and I think that's where my problem is, but I'm not sure how to fix that. (The variables are called 'cardOnePoints' and  'cardTwoPoints'.) Can anyone help me with that or tell me if there's anything else I'm doing wrong?

```
function getCookieOne(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if(x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function setCookieOne(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
} 

var winnerCount;
var getCount = getCookieOne('getCount');

function winnerCount()
{
    if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21)
    {
        winnerCount = getCount + 1
    }
    else 
    {
        winnerCount = getCount
    };
}

function countWinner()
{
    return winnerCount
}

function checkCookie()
{
    var username=getCookieOne("username");
    var gamesWonCount=getCookieOne("gamesWonCount");

    function winnerCounter() 
    {
        var gamesWin
        if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21)
        {
            gamesWin=++winnerCount;
        }
        else 
        {
            gamesWin=winnerCount
        };
        return gamesWin
    }

    if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
        alert("Sup " + username+ "!!! Woah man, you've won "
            + countWinner() + " game(s)!!!");
    }
    else 
    {
        username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
        if (username!=null && username!="")
        {
            setCookieOne("username",username,365);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use localStorage unless you need to support < IE8. You can store permanent variables like an array: `localStorage["name"] = whateverAskedTheUsersName` http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that applies to calling these variables after they've been altered?

Comment: Please use proper tabbing in future. Also, you seem to use semicolons in an odd way

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind but that doesn't really help solve the issue at hand?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things going on.  And some superfluous code.
I think the main problem stems from having a cookie called "gamesWonCount" and another cookie called "getCount".  You also have 2 variables and a function that keep track of this number (winnerCount, gamesWin, winnerCount()).

The first thing is to keep track of that number in one place.  Let's call it "winnerCount".

Now let's create  a function called "calculateWinnerCount", this will calculate the number of wins based on your card results.  Note that the base amount of "winnerCount" is set to your cookies value.

Since we're always manipulating the variable called winnerCount we can use that in the alert function.

Here is the code:

```
function getCookieOne(c_name)
{
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
     x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
     y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
     x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
     if (x==c_name)
     {
        return unescape(y);
     }
  }
}

function setCookieOne(c_name,value,exdays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
    expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
} 

var winnerCount = getCookieOne('gamesWonCount') || 0;

function calculateWinnerCount() {
  if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21) {
    winnerCount = winnerCount + 1;
  }
}

function checkCookie()
{
  var username=getCookieOne("username");

  if (username!=null && username!="") {
    alert("Sup " + username+ "!!! Woah man, you've won "
        + winnerCount + " game(s)!!!"
        );
  } else {
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
    if (username!=null && username!="") {
     setCookieOne("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how you are using or calling these functions.  But if you call calculateWinnerCount() at the end of every card game, it should add a number to your winnerCount variable which holds the number of total wins that you have stored in your cookie and that you have won today.

You may also want to set the cookie value everytime you calculateWinnerCount() like this:

```
function calculateWinnerCount() {
  if (cardOnePoints + cardTwoPoints === 21) {
    winnerCount = winnerCount + 1;
    setCookieOne("gamesWonCount", winnerCount, 14);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My code was getting pretty messy because I've tried so many different ways to solve it, so I appreciate you helping out with that, but even so, the counter is still returning only a value of 0 regardless of how many times the user has actually won. I really think the problem is with having to call variables (cardOnePoints and cardTwoPoints) that have been altered by a previous function?

Comment: Unfortunately, from here I can't tell where exactly the problem lies.  You can always create a test app on JsFiddle and post it here. That usually gets the best results.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, you were right in your initial guess.  The calculateWinnerCount() function does not have access to the values stored in "cardOnePoints" and "cardTwoPoints".  This is because those variables are defined in the dealHand() function. That means they are only accessible within that function.  A quick fix, is to move the definitions out of the functions so the value is accessible globally.  So "var cardOnePoints; var cardTwoPoints;" should be moved outside of the DealHand() function.  This will fix it, but note it is not a good solution because those variables become global.  Read about scope.